# What does (10%2) mean?

Tags: c, operators, modulo, modulus

What does the code `(10%2)` mean?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive question title next time--e.g. "What does % mean?"

Comment: It's a way to write `0`.

Comment: @Lese majeste So he should use a less descriptive, ambiguous title like "What does % mean?". % can mean a number of things, including percentage...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`%` is the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus) operator.

So this essentially says - what is the remainder of 10 divided by 2?

```
10 % 2 == 0
10 % 5 == 0
10 % 7 == 3
10 % 3 == 1
```

Answer (score 4):

10 modulo 2, or in other words, the remainder of 10 divided by 2.

`10 % 2` is `0` because there is no remainder after you divide by 2.

`10 % 3` -> this would divide by 3, which results in a remainder of `1` (10 = 3*3 + 1)

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator `(%)` computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second.

Answer (score 2):

10 % 2 should give you 0.
It is the MODULUS operator

Answer (score 1):

10%2 is 0, 10 divided by 2, rest is 0. This can also mean that number is even.